# Unable to load tabbed pages with data

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, model-view-controller

I have a task where I have to tab 3 different html pages under 3 tabs. All these pages load the grids with data as soon as user navigates to them. I am able to tab my html pages.There is a working plunkr of that. http://plnkr.co/edit/0XgquovKIICmgGcSVSef?p=preview
But the problem is now i cant load the pages with data as earlier. Where have I  possibly gone wrong? These tabbed pages dont load the grids with data.
 Html

```
<style>
    ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    li {
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-bottom-width: 0;
        margin: 3px 3px 0px 3px;
        padding: 5px 5px 0px 5px;
        background-color: none;
        color: none;
    }
</style>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs"
                ng-class="{active:isActiveTab(tab.url)}"
                ng-click="onClickTab(tab)">{{tab.title}}</li>
        </ul>
        <div id="mainView">
            <div ng-include="currentTab"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller code :

```
b360MyUtilities.controller("TabsController",
    [
    "$scope",
    function ($scope) {

        $scope.tabs = [{
            title: 'PlanSetupStatus',
            controller: "PlanSetupStatusController",
            templateUrl: "app/templates/views/utilities/PlanSetupStatus.html"

        }, {
            title: 'MigrationScheduled',
            controller: "MigrationScheduledController",
            templateUrl: "app/templates/views/utilities/MigrationHistory.html"
        }, {
            title: 'MigrationHistory',
            controller: "MigrationHistoryController",
            templateUrl: "app/templates/views/utilities/MigrationScheduled.html"
        }];

        $scope.currentTab =  "app/templates/views/utilities/PlanSetupStatus.html"

        $scope.onClickTab = function (tab) {
            $scope.currentTab = tab.templateUrl;
        }

        $scope.isActiveTab = function (tabUrl) {
            return tabUrl == $scope.currentTab;
        }
    }]);
```

Comment: ng-include doe not refresh a controller just a template... here you're trying load a controller, I would use ui-router and ui-sref this will let you load the controller and template...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a comment, but Ill explain here in further details.
the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/0XgquovKIICmgGcSVSef?p=preview) you gave shows a simple template change but the controller stay the parent controller or base.
you on the other hand want to add unique data and actually render a different page.

so if you're using ui-router the solution is really simple... define 3 routes for the tabs and then use something like:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li ng-class="{active: 'PassageTab' === currTab}" ng-if="isReadingComprehension || showSATPassage()">
            <a ui-sref=".editKeywordParametersBase.editQuestionPassage({questionType: questionType})" ng-click="moveToTab('PassageTab')">
             {{ltgLabels.PASSAGE_LABEL}}
            </a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{active: 'SPRQuestionEditing' === currTab}" ng-if="isSPR">
            <a ui-sref=".editSPRQuestion" ng-click="moveToTab('SPRQuestionEditing')">
             {{ltgLabels.MAIN_SPR_QUESTION}}
            </a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{active: 'NumericEntryQuestionEditing' === currTab}" ng-if="isNumericEntry">
            <a ui-sref=".editNumericEntryQuestion" ng-click="moveToTab('NumericEntryQuestionEditing')">
              {{ltgLabels.NUMERIC_ENTRY_TITLE}}
           </a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{active: 'QuestionEditing' === currTab}" ng-if="isMultipleChoice">
            <a ui-sref=".editQuestion" ng-click="moveToTab('QuestionEditing')">
             {{ltgLabels.MAIN_QUESTION_TAB_LABEL}}
            </a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{active: 'Keyword' === currTab}">
            <a ui-sref=".editKeywordParametersBase.editQuestionkeywords({questionType: questionType})" ng-click="moveToTab('Keyword');">
              {{ltgLabels.KEYWORDS_TITLE}}
            </a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{active: 'QuestionParams' === currTab}">
            <a ui-sref=".editQuestionParameters({questionType: questionType})" ng-click="moveToTab('QuestionParams')">
              {{ltgLabels.QUESTION_PARAMETERS_TITLE}}
            </a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{active: 'VersionHistory' === currTab}">
            <a ui-sref=".versionHistory({questionType: questionType})" ng-click="moveToTab('VersionHistory')">
              {{ltgLabels.VERSION_HISTORY}}
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

if you dont want to do that... you can always inject the controller to your template (I dont like that solution but it should work).
like:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" class="template" id="addLegTemplate">
<div ng-controller='myController'>
<!--html for adding a new leg-->
</div>
```

and if you dont like any of those then just have all the data in the controller that holds the tabs they will be auto connected to that scope.

Comment: I used the 2nd solution you gave and it is working like a charm. Thanks for your guidance

Comment: how can i disable a particular Tab?

Comment: disable or remove? you can add ng-disabled or ng-if or ng-show/hide according to some condition you want..

Comment: I just want the third tab to not to respond. I have done this thing here with tabs, http://plnkr.co/edit/X5ILJAkkfzcU6zBvYCfl?p=preview. but with the <li> tags i m not able to do the same

Comment: you can then just do it in the controller... something like if(!condition){$scope.currentTab = tab} or something like that